# MySQL IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT - Full SQL Example (not a duplicate)

Tags: mysql, exists, insert-update

I have seen a few snippets for this issue, but none of them completely answer the problem. I have cobbled together a version that phpMyAdmin initially doesn't complain about, but when I execute, it complains...

```
SELECT IF( EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM opts
  WHERE field_from_tbl1=47 AND field_from_tbl2=153) THEN
                  UPDATE tbl3
                  SET acct_id='update@us.com', 
                  id_type='email',
                  status='valid',
                  change_log=CONCAT(change_log, '|this_change_log_update|'),
                  bool1=false,
                  bool2=true
                  WHERE field_from_tbl1=47 AND field_from_tbl2=153
  ELSE
          INSERT INTO tbl3 (field_from_tbl1, field_from_tbl2, acct_id, id_type, status, change_log, bool1, bool2)
          VALUES (47, 153, 'insert@us.com', 'email', 'valid', '|this_change_log_update|', false, true)
```

A couple of notes: the field values from the other two tables can't individually be UNIQUE. It might be OK to make it where both in a combination are forced to be unique, but I haven't been able to figure that out. So, I am working on the assumptive limitation that the DB will not force these to be unique, which I think removes my option to use REPLACE. Also, you might notice that ")" is missing from the IF statement. When I attempt to add it, the darn thing complains. One post here suggests adding ", 1, 0)" before the THEN in line 3, but that errors also. Lastly, you might notice I am using CONCAT on the change_log field so we don't replace the existing value, but rather add to it.

Comment: You can't use `IF` this way to conditionally do two different types of DML statements in MySQL.  You can move this logic into your PHP code, or maybe look into using an upsert ([check here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)).

Comment: I don't think I can do this. As I stated, I can't use 47 as a unique key in tbl3--I will have more records in tbl3 for 47 matched to other values like 153. However, 47 is a key in tbl1. Also, I can't use 153 as a unique key in tbl3--I will have more records in tbl3 for 153 matched to other values like 47. Think like this: person to company. There will be many people dealing with the same company, AND a company will deal with many people. I can't use your ALTER TABLE and still do that unless it actually makes the relationship between 47 and 153 n tbl3 the actual key. Is that what it does?

Answer (score 1):

As @TimBiegeleisen says, **if** you have an index (primary or unique) on `field_from_tbl1` and `field_from_tbl2` you could use an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to perform this action. This should work:

```
INSERT INTO tbl3 (field_from_tbl1, field_from_tbl2, acct_id, id_type, status, change_log, bool1, bool2)
VALUES (47, 153, 'insert@us.com', 'email', 'valid', '|this_change_log_update|', false, true)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    SET acct_id='update@us.com', 
        id_type=VALUES(id_type),
        status=VALUES(status),
        change_log=CONCAT(change_log, VALUES(change_log)),
        bool1=VALUES(bool1),
        bool2=VALUES(bool2)
```

The `VALUES` function copies the matching value from the `INSERT` part of the statement to the `UPDATE`.

If necessary, you could add an appropriate index with `ALTER TABLE`:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl3 ADD UNIQUE KEY (field_from_tbl1, field_from_tbl2)
```

Comment: I don't think I can do this. As I stated, I can't use 47 as a unique key in tbl3--I will have more records in tbl3 for 47 matched to other values like 153. However, 47 is a key in tbl1. Also, I can't use 153 as a unique key in tbl3--I will have more records in tbl3 for 153 matched to other values like 47. Think like this: person to company. There will be many people dealing with the same company, AND a company will deal with many people. I can't use your ALTER TABLE and still do that unless it actually makes the relationship between 47 and 153 n tbl3 the actual key. Is that what it does?

Comment: The `ALTER TABLE` makes (47, 153) the actual key (not 47 or 153 individually) - so to use your example,  it will only refer to the relationship between company 47 and person 153.

Comment: I would also note that if the combination of (47, 153) is not unique then there's no way to update a single entry in the table.

Comment: Nick, I stated that I could not make 47 and 153 individually unique. It is the combination that is unique. However, no one proffered a way to approach this in SQL, so I created a two-step approach in the webserver instead.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was not able to convey to you that that is exactly what this answer does. It does not rely on 47 and 153 being individually unique it only relies on the combination being unique.